# How to make two paragraph to one paragraph with display flex

Tags: html, css

I want to move `View More` text to end of the first paragraph. How to make it with not changing current style and not using `!important`. Is it impossible?

```css
.main {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #eee;
    display: flex;
}
.main p {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus euismod sem quis felis sollicitudin, molestie
    vehicula lacus venenatis. Aenean sollicitudin malesuada neque. Integer vel molestie lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum
    primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Vivamus pretium purus sed iaculis faucibus. In
    quis dictum augue. Nunc porta vestibulum turpis et dictum. Ut cursus laoreet euismod. Nam at dapibus libero. Donec
    lacinia erat at nisl mollis mollis. In consectetur nisi at massa scelerisque consequat. Etiam quis nisi ut massa
    fermentum fermentum. Suspendisse ultrices, justo sit amet porttitor pretium, lorem nulla blandit augue, vel tempus
    elit enim nec dui. Aenean suscipit quam eu eros pulvinar, id accumsan ante euismod.
  </p>
  <p>View More</p>
</div>
```

My expected result is like this:
[image]

Comment: Remove the default spacing from the with `p { margin: 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

you can add `flex-direction: column;` to your `.main` class

```css
.main {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #eee;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.main p {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus euismod sem quis felis sollicitudin, molestie
    vehicula lacus venenatis. Aenean sollicitudin malesuada neque. Integer vel molestie lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum
    primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Vivamus pretium purus sed iaculis faucibus. In
    quis dictum augue. Nunc porta vestibulum turpis et dictum. Ut cursus laoreet euismod. Nam at dapibus libero. Donec
    lacinia erat at nisl mollis mollis. In consectetur nisi at massa scelerisque consequat. Etiam quis nisi ut massa
    fermentum fermentum. Suspendisse ultrices, justo sit amet porttitor pretium, lorem nulla blandit augue, vel tempus
    elit enim nec dui. Aenean suscipit quam eu eros pulvinar, id accumsan ante euismod.
  </p>
  <p>View More</p>
</div>
```

Edit: you can't do that with `flexbox` however, you can do that with `display: inline`

```css
.main {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #eee;
    display: inline;
}
.main p {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus euismod sem quis felis sollicitudin, molestie
    vehicula lacus venenatis. Aenean sollicitudin malesuada neque. Integer vel molestie lacus. Vestibulum ante ipsum
    primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Vivamus pretium purus sed iaculis faucibus. In
    quis dictum augue. Nunc porta vestibulum turpis et dictum. Ut cursus laoreet euismod. Nam at dapibus libero. Donec
    lacinia erat at nisl mollis mollis. In consectetur nisi at massa scelerisque consequat. Etiam quis nisi ut massa
    fermentum fermentum. Suspendisse ultrices, justo sit amet porttitor pretium, lorem nulla blandit augue, vel tempus
    elit enim nec dui. Aenean suscipit quam eu eros pulvinar, id accumsan ante euismod.
  </p>
  <p>View More</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I couldn't explain correctly. Just updated my question, please see the screenshot.

Comment: see my updated comment

Comment: That's the problem. I have to use `flex` only.

Comment: for me the nearest you can get is adding `align-items: flex-end` in your `.main`. Maybe there are css masters out here who could pull off this.